Configuring `next-auth` CognitoProvider to pass `identity_provider`
Project details

Next JS (version 14)
AWS Cognito (Google & Facebook sign-in integrated)

Regular login is handled inside my application, with the help of aws sdks
For google & facebook sign-in, I redirect my app to Cognito hosted UI domain


next-auth library to handle user session (version 4)

Here is a code excerpt to handle cognito authorization through next-auth
import CognitoProvider from 'next-auth/providers/cognito';

...

CognitoProvider({
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  issuer: process.env.ISSUER,
  async authorize(params, options) {
    const { provider } = params;
    return {
      ...options,
      params: {
        ...options.params,
        identity_provider: provider,
      },
    };
  },
});

In another file, I call signIn like the following
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';

...

const provider = 'google'; // or 'facebook'
await signIn('cognito', { provider });

The purpose of the above code is to be able to pass the provider so that when next-auth redirects, it can pass the appropriate identity_provider to Cognito so that their default UI is bypassed for my provider's login interface.
I am under the impression that it worked in some previous versions, but not in (next-auth) version 4. Need to know how to do that in version 4.
I skimmed through next-auth's github library to figure out a clue, unfortunately the solution wasn't apparent to me from my research there.

Using authorize method is applicable when you're using the CredentialsProvider of next-auth.
You can pass your query/search params through the 3rd parameter of signIn function now.
const signInOptions = { 
  callbackUrl: 'https://your-domain.com', 
  redirect: true // or false, whatever is needed
}
// const signInOptions = undefined; // If you want the defaults 

const signInAuthParams = { 
  identity_provider: 'Google' // or 'Facebook'
}

await signIn('cognito', signInOptions, signInAuthParams);


